# Why am i getting activation error for Javonet enterprise license in brand new PC

Tags: javonet

We have Javonet enterprise license and have been using it for a software application for more than 6 months. When i try to run the application with the same license in brand new PC, it gives the error message: com.javonet.JavonetException: Unknown activation error: The remote name could not be resolved: 'ads.sdncenter.pl'. But when i turn on Wifi it works. How do i make the license work without the wifi or internet. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on activation type you are using. For enterprise license for internal, development, test and build servers you can use standard runtime activation which requires internet connection and generates license on demand for each new machine where it is executed.

For production usage you can switch to compile time activation where you use Project Activation Tool to generate license file bound to your .NET libraries. This file included in your application will let you run Javonet anywhere without internet connection.

You can read more here: https://www.javonet.com/java-devs/guides/runtime-vs-offline-vs-compile-time-activation/

In your case it looks you try to use runtime activation without internet connection and therefore receive error that activation server cannot be reached.

To use your software without internet connection switch to compile time activation as described here:
https://www.javonet.com/java-devs/guides/project-activation-tool/

Comment: It works fine first time with project generator tool, but we created another build of our project & put the same javonet.lic & project genertor tool in  the project & when we try to run the new build in the same machine in offline, it says "* Detected previously generate Javonet.lic file. File has been deleted.License type must be: JavonetProfessional or JavonetEnterprise [ERROR]: License generation was executed with no hardware ID check mode '-nohid' but license key used is not allowed for disabling hardware ID check. Please contact Javonet support."  What do i do now?

Comment: @KumarSri project generator tool should be used only on your build server with internet access. You should not include it in your final package and run on target machines and therefore never run it offline. With each new build you just delete old lic, run project generator which gives you new lic for current build and you just distribute your product with this lic. It should work on any machine as long as binaries are the same. The license type error looks like you have typo or casing issue in license type argument make sure it is case sensitive JavonetEnterprise or JavonetProfessional